# Wrap figures in Doxygen-generated HTML docs

Tags: doxygen

I am making a documentation using Doxygen, and using the HTML output only.
I would like to include figures, if possible, with captions and wrapped.
As I understood, I can use HTML-only parts in the source. My attempt is

```
\image html test.png "A test figure"
    @htmlonly
<IMG SRC=”test.png” ALIGN=”left” HSPACE=”50” VSPACE=”50”/>
    @endhtmlonly
```

The result is that the \image generated picture appears, but only the spacekeeper for the  generated version. Do I wrong something? How can I insert a captioned figure, wrapped with text?

Comment: Doxygen does not copy the files specified by <IMG...> automatically, specify the files in HTML_EXTRA_FILES in the Doxyfile.

Comment: htmlonly is not for html code. it is for documentation that you want in the HTML output (and not in the other output formats RTF, MAN, etc)